# VBA, count syllables for any different language

Tags: vba, ms-office, ms-word

I know this is widely discussed on different threads over the net.

I am German, so most of the techniques shown are not suitable for me.

I thought to use the build in ability of MS Office’s auto hyphenation. Then split along the (hidden) soft hyphens and count the elements.

Something like this.

```
Private Function CountSyllables(TxtIn As String) As Long
    ActiveDocument.AutoHyphenation = True
    syllablesArray= Split(ActiveDocument.Content, "^-")
    CountSyllables=UBound(syllablesArray) + 1
End Function
```

But this does not work. Looks like I am splitting along the wrong character.

Can anybody help?

Comment: you probably need to split each individual word